# How to use find by userId or null in typeorm?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, typeorm

I using typeorm with sql.

I want to get all `Product` against `userId` or where I don't have `userId` (null).

How can I do that with a `find` function?

This code does not return results as expected:

```js
const userId = 22;
    
Product.find({
  where: {
    user: IsNull() || userId
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array to `where` which is effectively an `OR` clause

```js
const userId = 22;

Product.find({
  where: [
    { user: IsNull() },
    { user: userId }
  ]
});
```